# How do I check if a button exists if I don't know the name?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, excel-2010

Is there a way to see if a button exists on a worksheet if I don't know the name?

I have code in "ThisWorkbook" that creates a button when the workbook is opened. However, I don't want it to create a button if the button is already there. So I need a way to detect if the button exists.

I had another way around this which didn't work, which I'll include just because!

The button, when clicked, creates a new worksheet, titled "Transpose Data". So if the button is there, that worksheet is there too. So I tried the following sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
        Sheets("Transposed Data").Activate

Errorhandler:
    MsgBox ("ERROR")
    With Worksheets("Program Sheet")
        Set rng = .Range("A4:C4")
        Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        With btn
            .Caption = "Click here to continue"
            .AutoSize = True
            .OnAction = "TableCreation"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I think this code should only create the button if it finds the transposed data worksheet isn't there, which is exactly what I want. However, this code just signifies an error every single time I try to run it. I've tested all of the parts individually, and they work, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

But, if there's a different way to detect if a button is already in a worksheet, I don't need this, because I can simply create an if/then statement!

Comment: Is it the only button on the sheet called `Program Sheet`?

Comment: Loop over the buttons in `.Buttons` and check each one to see if any have the caption "Click here to continue".

Comment: If you name it when it's created, your code can test for the specific name.

Comment: If a button is detected, that means multiple buttons are on the sheet. If there are zero, I want to create one button!

Comment: `#1` in my example below should work for you in that case. It only adds a button if there are a zero buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways to do this:

1) Check whether the button already exists or not (**assumes there is only one button**)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim btn As Button, rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Program Sheet")
        If .Shapes.Count = 0 Then     //i.e. there aren't any buttons...
            Set rng = .Range("A4:C4")
            Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)

                With btn
                    .Caption = "Click here to continue"
                    .AutoSize = True
                    .OnAction = "TableCreation"
                End With

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

2) Check whether the sheet `Transposed Data` already exists or not

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open1()
    Dim btn As Button, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = Sheets("Transposed Data")

    If sht Is Nothing Then  //i.e. there is not worksheet called "Transposed Data"
        With Worksheets("Program Sheet")
            Set rng = .Range("A4:C4")
            Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)

                With btn
                    .Caption = "Click here to continue"
                    .AutoSize = True
                    .OnAction = "TableCreation"
                End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set sht = Sheets("Transposed Data")` will raise an error if the sheet doesn't exist, so you would need to wrap it in `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: @TimWilliams - Good spot. You are right. I'll update the code accordingly. Thanks.